# How can I compare LocalDateTime in JSON after parsing it out of an Object with the same filed in the object and ignore millisecond in the comparing?

Tags: java, json, compare, objectmapper, localdatetime

I'm testing this scenario :

I have an Object on my Test which has a `LocalDateTime`.

When I'm creating a JSON out of this Object via ObjectMapper, the result would be different because in the Object I have millisecond and in the JSON I don't have.

It is the line which compare the content in the response body with the string out of object:

```
assertThat(jsonOutOfTheObject, is(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)));
```

in Object the `LocalDateTime` filed would be something like:

```
2022-06-30T19:42:57.118286
```

and in the JSON-body:

```
2022-06-30T19:42:57
```

So they are not the same, and the test will be failed.

I tried `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)` and `withNano(0)` but they doesn't always give me the valid result, because if the millisecond will be more than 500000, they round it up.

Any solution?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that the truncate works fine, the problem is the `LocalDateTime` value in the JSON has been rounded up!

Comment: Documentation of [`truncatedTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) doesn't mention that this method does rounding.  And if you look at the source code, you see that it does *integer division* and the hood, there's no rounding. Hence, it can't the reason of your issue. A quote: `... returns a copy of the original date-time with fields smaller than the specified unit set to zero. For example, truncating with the minutes unit will set the second-of-minute and nano-of-second field to zero. `

Comment: Can you provide a minimum amount of code that would allow to reproduce the problem? [*See*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You are right, the truncatedTo() works fine, the problem is the localDateTime value in the json has been rounded up! I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

I added this cod for handling round up:

```
  private static final int MILLISECOND_EDGE_FOR_ROUND_UP = 500000000;

  private LocalDateTime roundUpSecond(LocalDateTime date) {
    if (date.getNano() > MILLISECOND_EDGE_FOR_ROUND_UP) {
        return date.plusSeconds(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return date.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's an serialization issue.
You must have a custom JsonSerializer because ObjectMapper can't handle LocalDateTime out of the box as far as i know.
Thus somewhere must be a pattern for serialization, like **SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")**. Append the milliseconds to this pattern and your comparison should be fine.

Comment: I tried addMixInAnnotations and added a jsonFormatter: @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"). but it has round up issue.

Comment: @ElhamJamshidpey Try this pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS". It should add the milliseconds to serialization.